# creation of formula field

Tags: formula-field, date

i have one custom object and in that i want to create a formula field based on date(custom field).

1) date field 
2) formula field(return type check box true or false)

case:

**if date is from previous month then i want to return true from the formula field otherwise false.**

can any one help me to create that kind of formula field.

i am pretty new for the formula field.

Thanks for the advance support.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write a formula using `MONTH` function

```
MONTH(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ) ==  (MONTH(TODAY())-1)
```

It return true only if previous month is equal to `Createdate`  field month. `DATEVALUE` is used to convert DateTime Field to Date.

Read about more formulas [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm)